# Get Last week date range from sunday to saturday moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need to get last week date range from sunday to saturday, but this code

```
moment().subtract(1, 'weeks').startOf('isoWeek')
moment().subtract(1, 'weeks').endOf('isoWeek')
```

gives date range from monday to sunday, How to get Last week date range from sunday to saturday with moment js?

Comment: why don't you substract another day after substracting a week ?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`isoWeek` gets you the start of week as per ISO 8601 standard. According to international standard ISO 8601, Monday is the first day of the week.

You may try using `week` instead of `isoWeek` in the method, which works as per your system settings (locale).

```js
console.log(moment().subtract(1, 'weeks').startOf('isoWeek').format('dddd'));
console.log(moment().subtract(1, 'weeks').endOf('isoWeek').format('dddd'));

console.log(moment().subtract(1, 'weeks').startOf('week').format('dddd'));
console.log(moment().subtract(1, 'weeks').endOf('week').format('dddd'));

console.log(moment().subtract(1, 'weeks').startOf('week').format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
console.log(moment().subtract(1, 'weeks').endOf('week').format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Read the difference [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/).

Comment: Awesome that worked, can it be formatted in YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: moment().subtract(1, 'weeks').startOf('week').format('yyyy-mm-dd') it didn`t work

Comment: @mano10 -- Yes, use appropriate tokens to format the object as per the requirements.

Comment: @31piy I've tried using this code today, but why is it that it returns `16-22` instead of `17-23` from last week's date range?  I've used it this way : `new Date(moment().subtract(1, 'weeks').startOf('week').format('YYYY-MM-DD'))`Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Thinking Simply: Set the Week Starting Day first

```
moment.updateLocale('en', {
    week : {
        dow :0  // 0 to 6 sunday to saturday
    }
});

//than get current week or get last week according to Sun -- Sat
'This Week': [moment().startOf('week'), moment().endOf('week')],
'Last Week': [moment().startOf('week').subtract(7,'days'), moment().endOf('week').subtract(7, 'days')],
```

you can simply use it with data-ranger in my case i am using "daterangepicker"
hopefull you will understand